# Is meta.skeptics the place to ask questions about teaching kids how to think like a skeptic ?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked the question "Do you know a joke or story, that teaches you something about being a skeptic ?" on Skeptics, but it was closed as being off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [our meta's FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> Avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with skeptics.stackexchange.com. This is not a random discussion area, it's a place for improving our community and website together.

This kind of discussion belongs [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/311/hub-of-reason).